# Path in a list of lists

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

So my problem is the following: I have this list of altitudes in a mountain and I want to make a function that can return the coordinates (row, column) of the altitude that is to be reached when climbing north. The climbing starts from any cell besides the cells in row 0, and ends when the cell above has a smaller/equal value than the one below. the climbing proceeds on a straight line upwards.

Each cell represents an altitude.

```
altitude = [
   [206,205,204,190,208],
   [190,194,206,197,203], 
   [196,196,205,201,193],
   [194,199,199,206,205], 
   [192,196,195,201,193], 
   [194,199,200,200,205], 
   [196,196,195,200,193] ]
```

What i tried ended up returning the coordinates of the cell above the one it is supposed to. It should return the coordinates of a cell which has a "smaller" cell on top, so to say.
And the value 'NONE' when it should return the coordinates of `start`

---

Start represents a pair of coordinates in altitudes.

---

For example, I should be obtaining these results, but I'm not:

```
climb_north(altitude, (1,0))
(0,0)

climb_north (altitude, 2,0))
(2,0)

climb_north (altitude, (4,0)
(2,0)
```

This is what I tried yet.

```
def climb_north(altitude, start):

    r = start[0]
    c = start[1]
    r_next = r - 1

    while (r_next >= 0):

       if (altitude[r][c]) > (altitude[r_next][c]):
           return (r_next, c)

       r, r_next = r_next, r-1

    return
```

So if anyone could help me it would be great! Thank you!

Comment: First, show how you call your function. What is `altitude` and `start`?

Comment: Start is a coordinate of a point in the list, altitude is the same as ' test' for the matter, but I'm editing the question. I'm sorry.

Comment: Please add an example of a function call, using your data (`test`). Add it to the question, not as an answer to my comment.

Comment: Done @DYZ, is it OK now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `altitude` follows the same format as `test` and `start` means the coordinate of `(row, column)` of which indices start from 0.

```
def climb_north(altitude, start):
    r0, c = start
    for r in range(r0, 0, -1):
        if altitude[r][c] > altitude[r-1][c]:
            if r == r0:
                return None
            else:
                return (r, c)
```

Using your test case, it works as follows:

```
climb_north(test, (5, 3)) # return (3,3)
climb_north(test, (3, 4)) # return None
climb_north(test, (1, 3)) # return None
```

Comment: why do you use '-1' in ```range```?

Comment: `range(r0, 0, -1)` means counting down from `r0` until `0`  with step `-1`.  So it is like `[r0, r0-1, ..., 1]`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is at the crux of your function:

```
   if (altitude[r][c]) > (altitude[r_next][c]):
       return (r_next, c)
```

As soon as you find a lower altitude, you return the row of that lower altitude.  Return `r` instead of `r_next`.  Also, since `r_next` is *always* `r-1`, do you really need to use the extra variavle?  For most of us, `r-1` is preferred, as in

```
   if (altitude[r][c]) > (altitude[r-1][c]):
       return (r, c)
```

Comment: But ```r_next``` is not always ```r-1```, that is my problem!